# SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I am going to install Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I have SQL Server 2008 Express already installed on my laptop along with Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

Do I have to uninstall SQL Server 2008 Express or will it be configured to operate in the 2010 Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright.

Make sure to install SQL Server 2008 SP1 though.

And also, don't make the mistake I did. If you happen to have win XP and you care about .NET framework 4, you have a problem because IIS 5.1 doesn't quite support it. You'll need to move to WIN 7.

Answer (score 2):

You are good to go. VS10 install will recognize your instance and not present sql as an install option.